# How to access struct in an array of structs

Tags: c, linux, struct

In a school assignment, I have to sort elements of struct that are located  in binary file. I think I have managed to sort it, but I have a problem with printing the result. I don't know how to access elements of struct because data must be read from file, so I only have address of the first struct in a array. (I think it should stay in array so that I can use qsort.)

This is the main code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "readfile.h"

typedef struct {
char name[32];
double value;
} record;

int nuvu(record* a, record* b){
    if(a->name < b->name) return -1;
    if(a->name > b->name) return 1;
    if(a->value < b->value) return -1;
    if(a->value > b->value) return 1;
}

int main()
{
    long N;
    unsigned char* p = readfile( "d.bin", &N );
    char* s;
    scanf("%s",&s);

    int k= N/sizeof(record);
    qsort(p,k,sizeof(record),(int(*)(const void*, const void *))nuvu);

    printf???

    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Additional:
readfile.c

```
#include "readfile.h"
unsigned char* readfile( char* filename, long* pN )
{
    FILE* f= fopen(filename,"rb");
    if(f==0){
        *pN=-1;
        return 0;
    }
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
    *pN=ftell(f);
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);

    char*p=malloc(*pN);
    if(p==0){
        *pN=-2;
        fclose(f);
        return 0;
    }
    size_t r = fread(p,1,*pN,f);
    if(r!=*pN){
        *pN=-3;
        fclose(f);
        free(p);
        return 0;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return p;
}
```

readfile.h

```
#ifndef __READFILE_H
#define __READFILE_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
unsigned char* readfile(char* filename, long* pN);

#endif /* __READFILE_H */
```

Comment: That's so wrong on many levels, I don't know where to start. 1. What on earth are you trying to do with `readfile`? read the whole file in a variable? 2. `if(a->name < b->name)` compares pointers, not the content. Use `strcmp` to compare two strings. 3. It would be much easier to declare an array of records (`record *record`), fill the array with the elements from the string, sort the array (not the string). Accessing is then very easy: `records[0]` for the first one, etc

Comment: Perhaps `nuvu` should `return 0;` at the end.

Comment: Declare `nuvu` to take `const void *` arguments so that it matches what `qsort` expects. Inside the `nuvu` function, assign the arguments to `const record *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the standard procedure for `qsort`, don't change its signature. Use `strcmp` as noted in comments. You have to figure out the logic of how the structure is to be sorted. The example below sorts by `record::name`, if `name` is the same, it tests `value`, in that order:

```
int nuvu(const void * a_, const void * b_)
{
    const record* a = a_;
    const record* b = b_;
    if(strcmp(a->name, b->name) == 0)
        return a->value > b->value;
    return strcmp(a->name, b->name);
}
```

Data is read as bytes in to `p`, it must be converted to *"array of records"* `record* arr = (record*)p;`. The number of items in the array should be `filesize/sizeof(record)` if everything went according to plan

```
int main(void)
{
    long filesize = 0;
    unsigned char* p = readfile("d.bin", &filesize);
    if(!p)
        return 0;

    int count = filesize / sizeof(record);
    record* arr = (record*)p;

    qsort(arr, count, sizeof(record), nuvu);

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%s %f\n", arr[i].name, arr[i].value);

    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `record::name` in C?? (scope resolution operator does not appear in C)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am just indicating which name it is. It's not valid C++ code either unless `name` is static.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest confusion you seem to have is "How do I read my array of structs back in?"

```
unsigned char* p = readfile( "d.bin", &N );
```

Is no way to begin. The concept of reading records from a binary file into an array of struct, is to read `sizeof (struct record)` bytes from the file into storage for type `struct record`. (*this will ignore for now the lack of serialization of the data, padding and portability issues, and the fact we are using a `typedef`*).

Knowing the file size, and knowing the `sizeof (struct record)` allows you to (1) validate the number of records you will read from the file, e.g. (`nbytes / sizeof (struct record)`) and (2) determine whether there are any stray bytes leftover that will not be part of the read (e.g. `if (nbytes / sizeof (struct record) != 0)`) which if present you should at least warn about.

Depending on the number of records you have to read and whether there is an upper bound for that number will determine whether you can use a fixed size array (or VLA) or whether you need to dynamically allocate (and reallocate) to address an unknown number of records or to prevent StackOverflow..  Regardless how you handle creating storage for your records -- *It is up to you to make sure you do not write beyond the bounds of the storage you create*.

Below, for example purposes we will simply work with an array of `100` records. The dividing line between what will fit on the stack and when you need to dynamically allocate will be compiler dependent, but any time you start thinking about tens of thousands of records, you need to consult your compiler documentation and start thinking about dynamic allocation.

`fread` provides a simple method to read binary records from a file and validate that you actually read the number of records you intended to read. For example, given a declaration of an array of `100` records in `rec`, you could do something like the following:

```
enum { MAXC = 32, MAXS = 100 }; /* if you need constants, define them */
...
    record rec[MAXS] = {{ .name = "" }};    /* array of 100 records */
    ...
    nrec = nbytes / sizeof *rec;   /* number of records based on file size */

    /* read / validate nrec records from file */
    if (fread (rec, sizeof *rec, nrec, fp) != nrec) {
        perror (fn);
        return 1;
    }
```

With your records successfully read from your file, using `qsort` to sort the records (either by `name` or by `value`) requires you to understand that the `const void *` pointers to be compared in your comparison function will be *pointer to rec*, so you must provide an appropriate cast within your comparison function to access and compare the values. For example to perform a string comparison on `name`, you can do something similar to the following:

```
/** record string comparison on name */
int reccmpname (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const record *ra = a,
                 *rb = b;
    return strcmp (ra->name, rb->name);
}
```

Other than that, the remainder of what your code lack is ***validation*** of each step in the process. Always, always, validate the return of any function you use and handle any errors you encounter. A minimal example, without splitting the code up between separate source files could be something like the following. Splitting up into separate source files is left to you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXC = 32, MAXS = 100 }; /* if you need constants, define them */

typedef struct {
    char name[MAXC];
    double value;
} record;

/** record string comparison on name */
int reccmpname (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const record *ra = a,
                 *rb = b;
    return strcmp (ra->name, rb->name);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    record rec[MAXS] = {{ .name = "" }};    /* array of 100 records */
    size_t nrec = 0;                        /* number of records from file */
    long nbytes = 0;                        /* number of bytes in file */
    char *fn = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "dat/records.bin";
    FILE *fp = fopen (fn, "rb");

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END) == -1) {    /* validate seek to end */
        perror ("fseek");
        return 1;
    }
    nbytes = ftell (fp);                    /* number of bytes in file */
    if (nbytes == -1) {
        perror ("ftell");
        return 1;
    }
    if (fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_SET) == -1) {    /* validate seek to start */
        perror ("fseek");
        return 1;
    }

    if (nbytes % sizeof *rec != 0) /* does file contain even no. or records? */
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: file size not multiple of record size.\n");

    nrec = nbytes / sizeof *rec;   /* number of records based on file size */

    /* read / validate nrec records from file */
    if (fread (rec, sizeof *rec, nrec, fp) != nrec) {
        perror (fn);
        return 1;
    }
    fclose (fp);    /* close file */

    printf ("\n=== unsorted records ===\n\n");  /* output unsorted */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrec; i++)
        printf ("%-32s  %g\n", rec[i].name, rec[i].value);

    qsort (rec, nrec, sizeof *rec, reccmpname); /* qsort records */

    printf ("\n=== sorted records ===\n\n");    /* output sorted */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrec; i++)
        printf ("%-32s  %g\n", rec[i].name, rec[i].value);

    return 0;
}
```

**note:** The data file used simply contained 100 struct records with dictionary words as `name` and random values as `value` shuffled before being written to the file.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/struct_rd_name_val_recs

=== unsorted records ===

Abscess                           4.15871e+08
Abject                            3.5743e+08
Abo                               6.87659e+08
Aboard                            2.02028e+09
Abase                             3.34319e+08
...
=== sorted records ===

A                                 3.66907e+08
Aaa                               5.59224e+07
Aaas                              1.45617e+09
Aardvark                          1.72828e+09
Aarhus                            1.95723e+09
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [] operator with a pointer:

```
struct my_struct {
  int i, j;
};
struct my_struct * ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct my_struct) * 10);
for(int n = 0; 10 > n; ++ n)
{
  ptr[n].i = n;
  ptr[n].j = n*2;
}
free(ptr);
```

Comment: Better still  `struct my_struct * ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof *ptr);`. If you later change the variable type, you don't have to worry about the pesky `sizeof(<var types>)`